# React setState is overwriting state

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with one input field of name, and its onChange method I have this following code:

```
    onChangeUpdateForm(e) {
    this.setState({
        currentService: {
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        }
    })
};
```

I want to update currentService's name with the new value, but everything in state gets overwritten. How can I update one single value of an object in state?

Comment: can you please show what your `state` object looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to update currentService's name with the new value, but everything in state gets overwritten.

Because you're replacing the entire object. Try this:

```
this.setState({
    currentService: {
        ...this.state.currentService,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }
});
```